# Extract tags from media received from Instagram API

Tags: python, api, instagram

example from python-instagram documentation in github:

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI

access_token = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
api = InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token)
recent_media, next_ = api.user_recent_media(user_id="userid", count=10)
for media in recent_media:
   print media.caption.text   # it gets caption text from each media
```

But, when I try this(only last line changed):

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI

access_token = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
api = InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token)
recent_media, next_ = api.user_recent_media(user_id="userid", count=10)
for media in recent_media:
   print media.tags  # attempt to get tags associated with each media
```

it says that media does not have "tags" attribute. I think response from Instagram API includes "tags" key.

What am I missing? How to get tags of media?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should make sure there is tags attribute. Like this:

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI

access_token = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
api = InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token)
recent_media, next_ = api.user_recent_media(user_id="userid", count=10)
for media in recent_media:
    if hasattr(media, 'tags'):
        print media.tags  # attempt to get tags associated with each media
    else:
        # you can check if there is tags attribute through this line
        print 'all the attributes of media are: ', repr(dir(media))
```

Comment: so, are you saying that if person who posted that media did not write any tags, there wont be any tags attribute? Does it not return empty list?

Comment: Or - use `tags = getattr(media, 'tags', [])` or whatever default value empty `tags` should take

Comment: @Jahongir Yes, I think so.

Comment: @m170897017 thank you, you were right. I tried with media which for sure has tags, and it worked